# Test if a variable is read-only

Tags: bash

To test if a variable is read-only, there are the following ugly hacks:

```
# True if readonly
readonly -p | egrep "declare -[:lower:]+ ${var}="

# False if readonly
temp="$var"; eval $var=x 2>/dev/null && eval $var=\$temp
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Why do you believe this to be important?

Comment: Ask for something does not make it important. Elsewhere elegant is not associate with important.

Comment: It's only important insofar as you care about the readability of your scripts. For example, being able to use either `[ -R varname ]` or `readonly -t varname` (`t` for test) to test for this would be elegant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a subshell seems to work. Both with local and exported variables.

```
$ foo=123
$ bar=456

$ readonly foo

$ echo $foo $bar
123 456

$ (unset foo 2> /dev/null) || echo "Read only"
Read only

$ (unset bar 2> /dev/null) || echo "Read only"
$

$ echo $foo $bar
123 456           # Still intact :-)
```

The important thing is that even is that the subshell salvages your RW ($bar in this case) from being unset in your current shell.

Tested with bash and ksh.

Answer (score 3):

You can also add an empty string to the variable, which still leaves its value alone, but is faster than using a subshell, e.g.:

```
foo+= 2>/dev/null || echo "Read only"
```

Captured as a function, it'd be:

```
is-writable() { eval "$1+=" >2/dev/null; }
```

Comment: If `foo` is unset, this test will set it to the null string, so you need to test for that, too.

Comment: In modern bash, if `foo` is unset and also has the nameref attribute, the test will fail even if `foo` isn’t readonly because the null string isn’t a valid variable name.

Comment: On the other hand, bash will help you avoid the danger of someone accidentally or deliberately writing something like “`is-writable 'rm -rf / #'`” (**Do not run that!**):  use a local nameref variable in your function instead of the eval.  Of course, if you happen to use a local varable that was previously set readonly, it’ll break your function.