# How can we check whether a variable is readonly or not in linux

Tags: readonly-variable

How can we check under **if**  whether a variable is readonly or not? Please Explain with Examples

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test if a variable is read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440842/test-if-a-variable-is-read-only)

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide any information of what are you talking about, but I guess you want to check a variable in bash.

If that is the case, this post may help you: [Test if a variable is read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440842/test-if-a-variable-is-read-only)

In future questions, I suggest you to provide more information about the environment you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

If you type the command **readonly** without arguments, it will print the list of the readonly variables. So you can write something like this:

```
readonly PI=3.14
PO=3.14
if [ "$(readonly | grep -w PI)" != "" ] ; then echo read-only ; else echo not read-only ; fi
if [ "$(readonly | grep -w PO)" != "" ] ; then echo read-only ; else echo not read-only ; fi
```

which will result in the following output:

```
read-only
not read-only
```